# Problems adding Google Analytics to iOS App

Tags: ios, ios5, google-analytics

When I run through implementing Google Analytics in my app, using this walk through:
http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/analytics_end_to_end.html

After adding the libGoogleAnalytics.a CFNetwork and libsqlite3.0.dylib frameworks, and added the GANTracker.h into my AppDelegate.m

I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GANTracker", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and the app won't even compile. My app is aimed at iOS 5.0

I'm pretty stuck. Any advice or work throughs would be very highly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure all required classes are added to your target

Comment: Did you have any resolution?  I am fighting this issue as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I actually figured out the answer after posting the comment.

Click on your project in the "Project Navigator", then click on your project under "Targets".  You then need to click on "Build Phases".  You need to make sure `libsqlite3.0dylib` and `CFNetwork.framework` are added to the "Link Binary WIth Libraries".  I had this, but what I didnt have was you also need to add `libGoogleAnalytics.a` to that same area.  That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Had the same problem when using Google's EasyTracker example.  Thank you!

Comment: I would have never found this one - adding the libGoogleAnalytics.a is a sneaky error.  Nice work.

Comment: In my case it was missing: CoreData.framework (probably because most answers here are from an older version of the library)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I add the AdSupport.framework for the missing `"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager"`

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the answer of @Etch.

Xcode 4.5 dropped armv6 and only supports armv7. Therefore, your lib might be an old version and you need to download version 1.5.1 onward. [Download here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources)

Issues: http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=232

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a Cordova based XCode project. And got stuck with these stupid errors before figuring out what the linking errors meant. So here is what you do..

First, make sure you follow the steps mentioned https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/GoogleAnalytics. Next make sure you have the following files under the project linked via Build Phases (You get that when you click on the project name.. figure it out)

1. GANTracker.h
2. libsqlite3.0.dylib
3. libGoogleAnalytics.a
4. CFNetwork.framework

Also make sure your Plugins folder has 2 files, GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.h and GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.m.

If that doesn't help resolve your bugs. Then God help you. Start praying. Or alternatively try a bug spray. See if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The solution was move the library to same level of .h files.
But I don't know why this work.

Answer (score 0):

In your Link Binary With Libraries under Build Phases under your target:

Make sure you **remove**  libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a if you added it.  And ensure you have AdSupport.framework and of course libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a.